# Use Entity Framework to map 3 existing database tables to 1 entity object

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, orm, mapping

I've got a database with no constraints declared in it (beyond primary keys), uses multiple layers of soft delete, and I need to map mult tables into a single entity object.  I've further detailed the boundaries of my problem below.  Insight would be appreciated.

**Desired Entity:**

```
Person {
PersonID
Age
Height
List(Of Behaviors)
}
```

I've got to figure out how to map this to the EXISTING Database using Entity Framework.
- When I delete it will actually be a soft delete
- When I create need to also set a StartDate (see below) on table rows
- When I update would like to set EndDate on current row, and create a new row.

**Existing Database:**
(Note:  a) I'm not allowed to change the structure to the database
        b) Beyond primary keys, not contraints exist on db (i.e. PersonID in PersonInfo has not been marked as foreign key)
        c) StartDate - can't be null
        d) EndDate - used for soft delete 
        e) because of d) - there might be multiple PersonInfo entries for 1 PersonID but only 1 will be current - not have an EndDate

**Tables:**

```
Person 
    PersonID (identity)
    StartDate
    EndDate

PersonInfo
    PersonInfoID (identity)
    PersonID
    Age
    Height
    StartDate
    EndDate

PersonBehavior
    PersonBehaviorID (identity)
    PersonID
    BehaviorID
    StartDate
    EndDate


Behavior
    BehaviorID (identity)
    Description
    StartDate
    EndDate
```

Comment: Also curious if I'd be better off just mapping these 3 tables as is into 3 separate POCO objects and then maybe wrapping the 3 into 1 on repository side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should create another object in a seperate classe, that classe will represent the 3 entitys you want to be wrapped. Then import all the stuff in 3 seperate object, then merge them in the class you've created. I recommend you to start building function in that class that wrap and unwrap the 3 entitys. Entity is quite hard to manipulate elseway.

Comment: So I would take Person, PersonInfo, PersonBehavior entities and create an amalgamated entity?

PersonAmalgamated {
Person
PersonInfo
LIst of PersonBehaviors
}